# How to prevent a user renaming the wiki welcome page?

Tags: permissions, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

We currently had a problem because a user unintentionally renamed the welcome page of a wiki (subsite) and thus there was no access to the wiki anymore.

I managed to get to the pages library of the wiki and rename it back to its original name, but the question remains:

How can I prevent that a user changes the name of the welcome page of the wiki but is still able to edit its contents?